# What do I need to do to be able to use keyboard combinations, instead of Touch Bar clicks?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, accessibility, touch-bar, voiceover

I am blind user and I must use a program which is an accessible with Voiceover, the Apple screen reader. That’s why I need a way to press keys instead of learning to click something which I don’t see.

On a MacBook Pro with Touch Bar, how do I use keyboard combinations, instead of Touch Bar clicks?

Comment: Can you give an example of a function you want to use?

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard shortcuts can be found in **System preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts**. You can set any shortcuts to any keyboard combinations you'd like. The default for voiceover is **Command + F5**, which can be changed.

The Touch Bar can also be set to only display the Function Keys, instead of app specific context keys. While you won't be able to feel the position of them, they will remain there when any app is open, acting like a standard keyboard rather than the Touch Bar.